# How to maintain elasticity of rubber band like it was initially?

Tags: office-supplies, hair

I use rubber band to keep my hair together. But day by day , as I use them, they start to lose their elasticity or I can say that their grip gets loose, within just 3-4 uses.
I want to know what I can do so that the rubber band doesn't lose it's grip and works like it did initially.

[image]

Rubber bands I use for my hair look like above.

Comment: The further you stretch the rubber band, the more "loose" it becomes.  I would suggest stretching it out as little as possible, even if that means it takes a little longer to get all of your hair through the middle.  I don't know of any hack to keep the elasticity in the rubber band.  I think it's just going to wear out, best you can hope for might be to slow it down.

Comment: Possible dublicate

 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/is-there-any-way-to-increase-a-rubber-bands-lifetime It says basically, don't get cheap rubber bands and they will last longer... not that I think you are buying cheap rubber bands, just that they are made cheaply :)

Comment: @Jared - Thank you Jared. It is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a rubber band is a thermodynamic object which does not contain any potential energy if loose (unstreached), thus it's to be declared as "cold" if loose.
When you stretch a rubber band, it warms up from the streaching and then contains potential energy which is needed to get back to it's old state.

Also, warm rubber bands are more elastic than cold ones.
Like shown [here](http://tuhsphysics.ttsd.k12.or.us/Research/IB10/RajeJaneHerm/index.htm).

Since rubber bands wear out faster when being overstretched, you should make them as elastic as possible prior to stretching by warming them up first.

Do not wrap them around your wrist to warm them if they're cold, it's better to put them into your pocket or hold them in your hands for a moment.
Once they're warmed up, your wrist is then a perfect place to store them to keep them warm.

Make sure the rubber band is warm before you wrap them around your hair.
Do not store them at cold temperatures.

And of course, higher quality is more durable.
There's a german proverb:

> "Wer billig kauft, kauft zweimal, wer sparen will gibt Geld aus."
> *If you buy cheap, you'll buy again. If you want to save money, pay more.*

Comment: You Sir speak like a true scholar

Answer (score 1):

I have found that keeping hairbands in an airtight container keeps them stretchy for much longer than if they are left out. Also if you use hair products such as gels or hairsprays your bands will break down faster than normal.